# URI handling: initiate Lync from browser links

Tags: macos, uri, lync, skype-for-business

I am able to initiate Lync client to call or IM/Video by generating links in my web app and the URI handling/external protocol handling by the brwoser OS. for example, a link like tel:666-666-6666 ; SIP:my@email.com and im:sip:my@email.com.

This works great on PC with all browsers and Lync 2010, 2013 and skype for business.

**My question**: Can this or a variant of this approach work on a Mac and with which Lync/Skype versions?

Answer (score 1):

The tel url schema is most commonly supported of the ones you listed and is documented at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2806#section-2.2 and whilst the support is going to be implementation specific it is supported definitely by macs https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html and Android https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/click-to-call/?hl=en via their sdks

Comment: But it is not clear if it should work by Lync for Mac 2011. It also seems that on Mac, the im: protocol opens iMessage and not Lync,

Comment: In that case you would need to change the default application for the tel: scheme on the mac itself.  I'm not a mac owner so don't know how to do this natively however a quick google returned the RCDefaultApp for Mac which allows you to do this.http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/14618/rcdefaultapp